# Java Plugin Pattern

Tags: java, plugin-pattern

I am a Java beginner and I would appreciate it if someone here can explain how to implement Martin Fowler's plugin pattern in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply, you define an interface for the operations you want to do, and pass an object at run time that implements that interface.  So, for example, you might have communications through local shared memory and through remote  TCP/IP.  You build an interface, call it `IConnection` that has `send()` and `recv()`, and then implement it in two classes, `LocalConnection` and `LongDistanceConnection`.

You then have some other class that needs to communicate, let's say `TelephoneCall`.

To make a local call, you do

```
TelephoneCall call = new TelephoneCall(new LocalConnection());
```

To make a long distance call, you do

```
TelephoneCall call = new TelephoneCall(new LongDistanceConnection());
```

and the signature of the constructor is

```
 public TelephoneCall(IConnection connect);
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Tip the wait staff as you leave.

Comment: This seems not to answer the pattern intent: Links classes during configuration rather than compilation. The same example implemented using let's say Spring DI would do it.

Comment: @grigory, I don't follow.  a new happens at run time.  if you don't want to do it in the ctor, it's no problem to have another method setConnection(Iconnection), but would that explain the pattern any better?

Comment: @Charlie: there is nothing else that may happen at runtime except "new LocalConnection()" because it was actually compiled, right. Hence, is my little comment on linking classes during compilation. Using Spring DI (or other DI tool for that matter) we can change this using configuration (say in xml files). No problems other that that.